# Adding another database to Django and it says "Apps aren't loaded yet"

Tags: django, django-models

I'm new to Django. I'm trying to add another database to my project. I got this error: `django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.`

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34114427/django-upgrading-to-1-9-error-appregistrynotready-apps-arent-loaded-yet/34115677), I added this code to my settings:

```
import django
django.setup()
```

I got the same error again.

A few solutions pointed to `django.contrib.sites` and `django.contrib.contenttypes`. So I made sure they're in `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'theme',
    'myapp',
    'debug_toolbar',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
]

SITE_ID = 1
```

A couple of solutions said to remove the apps one by one to see what's wrong, so I removed `theme`, `myapp`, and `debug_toolbar` one by one, and then all at the same time. But I still got the error.

I point to a database router in `settings.py` too:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'movies': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'movie_data.sql'),
    }
}

from . import router # I shifted this to the top of the file later.
DATABASE_ROUTERS = [router.MoviesRouter]
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43067696/apps-arent-loaded-yet-and-django-core-exceptions-improperlyconfigured-in-dj) solution makes sense so I tried putting `DATABASE_ROUTERS = [router.MoviesRouter]` all the way down at the end of `settings.py`, but it didn't help.

`urls.py` in the same directory as `settings.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf import settings

from myapp import views as myapp_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('myapp/', myapp_views.MoviesListView.as_view(), name='movie_list'),
]
```

In `router.py`, in the same directory as `settings.py`:

```
from myapp import models

class MoviesRouter(object):

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):

        model = models.Movies

        if model._meta.app_label == 'myapp':
            return 'movie_data.sql'

        return None
```

I added `model = models.Movies` to the code above because there was an error: `TypeError at /myapp/ and db_for_read() missing 1 required positional argument: 'model'`. But none of code I read on GitHub has anything like it. So I don't know if I'm doing the right thing even if it made the error go away.

`models.py` in the app:

```
from django.db import models

class Movies(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    adult = models.TextField()
    original_language = models.TextField()
    original_title = models.TextField()
    title = models.TextField()
    overview = models.TextField()
    release_date = models.DateTimeField()
    genres = models.TextField()
    production_countries = models.TextField()
    videos = models.TextField()
    images = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        app_label = "myapp"
        db_table = "movies"
```

(I'm not sure yet if I should add all these fields myself. The database comes with all of them already.)

`views.py` in the app (where I am trying to practise using `generic.Listview` for the first time):

```
from django.views import generic
from .models import Movies

class MoviesListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Movies
    template_name = r'myproject/theme/templates/myapp/myapp.html'
```

The code started out the same as in the documentation on [multiple databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/multi-db/). But reading through other articles, tutorials, and code on GitHub has changed it here and there. So, there may be several mistakes in the code. I don't know for sure which mistakes affect the problem, but I think my primary problem is the one in my first paragraph: `Apps aren't loaded yet.` What have I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked on the Django IRC channel and the solution turns out to be:

1. Remove `import django` and `django.setup()` from `settings.py`.
2. Instead of `return 'movie_data.sql'`, return the table in the database instead: `return 'movies'`.
3. The `DATABASE_ROUTERS` list should contain strings. So instead of `[router.MoviesRouter]`, use `['router.MoviesRouter']`.

Thank you, Django IRC channel.