# Apps aren't loaded yet when trying to import model in a celery tasks file

Tags: python, django, celery

Before any explanations, here is the tree of my project

```
| projectname
|____|__init__.py
|____|celery.py
|____|settings.py
|____|urls.py
|____|wsgi.py
|app1
|app2
```

Here's my celery.py

```
from celery import Celery
from celery import shared_task

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'projectname.settings')
app = Celery('projectname')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()

from app1.models import *

@share_task
def tasks():
     ''' '''
```

Every time I try importing `models` to the `celery.py` file with this line `from app1.models import *` I got:

> django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

And the local server stops working all of a sudden. 
[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43067988/9865749) is related to a similar problem, but not sure it's the case here.

**What I want is to import some models to the file, so I can use them for some queries.**

I got a little clue about what can be wrong, but not sure.

**`views`** import stuff from **`models.py`**
**`views`** import stuff from **`celery.py`** like the task to be executed
**`celery.py`** tries to import stuff from **`models`**.

So that circle like a snake that bites its own tail is weird to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is when you try to **upload your tasks before Django loads the configuration()** with

```
from app1.models import *
```

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'projectname.settings')
app = Celery('projectname')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

Off course Celery will detect tasks in `celery.py` file, remember that you have imported everything from `celery.py` to `__init__.py` to let Django loads them (Celery stuff,...) every time the project starts.

**__init__.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

So with this case you're importing models in that `celery.py` file let's say `__init.py__` as well, Your models will be imported before Django loads its configuration while Apps in your `settings.py` aren't built yet.

You should not import Django app stuffs into your `__init__.py` file, modules/apps are built before Django loads the configuration(settings.py), this will raise an Error **Apps aren't loaded yet** if you try to upload like `models` in `__init__.py` file.

According to [the documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html), Celery has `app.autodiscover_tasks()` able to discover every tasks found in any well-registered app in `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`. Instead of importing tasks in the `celery.py` Just create a `tasks.py` file in all your apps.

```
| projectname
|____|__init__.py
|____|celery.py # contains app.autodiscover_tasks()
|____|settings.py
|____|urls.py
|____|wsgi.py
|app1
|____|tasks.py
|app2
|____|tasks.py
```

> Tasks may work in `celery.py` file, but not when uploading Model from apps, use app.autodiscover_tasks() instead
>
> Use as well absolute imports from the future if needed

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

Comment: Last night, I ended up doing this, it works well! thanks for your answer, and also for the details, it helps me understand what was wrong. I was supposed to be happy to solve this issue, but I'm struggling with another one (Sad), not a related issue, maybe I will ask another question, anyway thank you. this answer is good, and the accepted one

Comment: I had to put myself in the same situation with the same issue to figure out what was wrong. glad it works,as you said, ***I bet my question is not awesome at all***, you were right.(laugh)

Comment: Question and answer both are very helpful. Saved my time and fixed my issue. Good work guys.