# django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet error in django, celery

Tags: django, django-models

I'm getting

> `django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet`

error in `django==2.0.2` and `celery==4.1.0`. No search helped me around. I tried

```
import django
django.setup()
```

But it seems that this did not work for me. Here is the traceback:

```
[2018-06-05 10:41:42,529: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task backend.ml.face_detection_request[891df311-fe6b-4456-8c30-84a0b9baf716] raised unexpected: AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.",)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 374, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 629, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/wandresearchrepo/wandhub/wandhub/backend/ml.py", line 89, in face_detection_request
    from backend.models import Image
  File "/home/user/backend/models.py", line 6, in <module>
    class Company(models.Model):
  File "/home/user/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 100, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/home/user/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 244, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/home/user/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 127, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Comment: i think you can't find because, other people put image in the question  instead of text.

Comment: @BearBrown just updated the question.

Comment: Possible error could be due to config issue in celery. Are you missing specifying the apps list?

Comment: @VinayP There are two apps in my project 1. backend 2. webapi added it in the installed_apps like `backend.apps.BackendConfig`, `webapi.apps.WebapiConfig`

Comment: take a look at this recent [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50671044/apps-arent-loaded-yet-when-trying-to-import-model-in-a-celery-tasks-file) or just add your celery configuration, and the tree of your project

Comment: My Project structure would be

`- proj/
  - manage.py
  - proj/
    - __init__.py
    - settings.py
    - celery.py
    - urls.py
- backend
   - tasks.py
- webapi`