# AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet. when using UserCreationForm

Tags: python, django, backend

I have looked high an low for someone with a similar issues as to mine. When I use djangos built-in UserCreationForm I get django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet. I've tried commenting out apps in INSTALLED_APPS in settings and still nothing. This only becomes and issues when I import UserCreationForm

Here is my code

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect


@login_required
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')


def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'registration/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

Here is the error I'm receiving

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 347, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 89, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Ian Doarn\PycharmProjects\BettingPool\pool\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "C:\Users\Ian Doarn\PycharmProjects\BettingPool\pool\views.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\forms.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 100, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 244, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 127, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Comment: Did you check this similar question? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34114427/django-upgrading-to-1-9-error-appregistrynotready-apps-arent-loaded-yet)

Comment: Post your setting.py

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue, I was importing views.py in my **init**.py. After removing the import statement in views.py everything worked perfectly!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43067988/6605269